# How to delay script in header tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Normally my head tag look like this

```
<head>
    <base href="https://www.example.com">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
```

When i click in div `id="test"`

```
<div id="test" onclick="change_head_element_fn()">test</div>
<script>
function change_head_element_fn(){
    // how to change head elements //
}
</script>
```

I want to change head tag to this

```
<head>
    <base href="https://www.example.com">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <meta name="test" content="ce12b86aedbe27ef62091245362376af">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//test.com/apu.php"></script>
</head>
```

How can i do ?

Comment: You want to add script tag in the `head` after a `div` click ?

Comment: Nicolas, yes..........

Comment: I'm just trying to clarify. It's possible but I don't think it will load the ressources

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achievable. If you have jQuery already loaded, you can do it like this:

```
function change_head_element_fn(){
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "//test.com/apu.php";
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  $("head").append(script); 
}
```

After this you should be able to use the desired script.

Answer (score 0):

**You can refer this example**

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  // Just replacing the value of the 'content' attribute will not work.
  $('meta[name=description]').remove();
  $('head').append('<meta name="description" content="this is new">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="description" content="this is old">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>

<button>Change description</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  /* button on function */
</script>
```